# How to get core code into different branches in git

Tags: git, version-control

I am working on one project. The customer needs 4 (maybe more) types of the application. These applications will differ in only 100 lines of code (button count) and these lines will probably never change. The rest of application will be the same.

I want to work in master branch and push these changes into the other 4 branches. I do not want to use cherry-pick (What if someone will forget to cherry-pick every commit to these branches..).

I am really new to git and I am trying to figure this out.

The best option I have found is to create 4 branches and change the code. Work normally in master branch and when the release of the new version time will come, I will merge master branch into these 4 branches and I will have the desired result (simple shell script would do this nicely).

I would like to hear someone else opinion. Like I said, I am really new to git and I do not think I found the best solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Branches is the way to do it.
Since you will have the same code as the base line and using branches will make your life easy to maintain.

Another solution can be to use subtree. You can have your single repo but instead of using branches you can manage your updated files with subtree/submodule.

The `subtree/submodule` will contain all the changes that you need to have.

---

Here is ageneral schema onhow submodules will look like:

[image]

---

And the same concept in subtree ( the image is no te exacly what you need but you can get the general idea to have diffrent content in a diffrent branch.)

[image]

Comment: I agree that large cores could be handled by subtrees and sumbodules. For now, I am dealing with difference in a single file. I have never worked with subtrees and submodules (only read about them). Do you think it is easier to manage than my solution? I see with subtrees I could have all versions (types) in one branch as subdirectories and still have it as a branches.

Comment: Exactly, you can look on subtree as a type of dependency manager, in your case its not a real dependency but a simple different file content.

Comment: The final appearance with subtrees looks nice. But it looks a liitle harder to handle than simple branches. In all ways I have to create branches (or new repos - not nice) and create subtrees from these branches (Dunno if I can do that - subtrees can be made of repos only?). I will stick with my solution for now and when I get used to git, I will try subtrees. I like the idea of having all versions (types) available in master branch, but it seems like a little overkill for me (and I cannot fail now - first release is in one month :-) ). Thank you